# How to calculate no of weeks , days past between two dates

Tags: php, date

I want to calculate weeks,days between 2 dates.

eg: `2013-12-25` to `2013-12-25` will output  `1 Day`

eg: `2013-12-22` to `2013-12-25` will output  `4 Days`

eg: `2013-12-18` to `2013-12-25` will output  `1 Week, 1 Day`

eg: `2013-12-18` to `2013-12-26` will output  `1 Week, 2 Days`

eg: `2013-12-16` to `2013-12-30` will output  `2 Weeks, 1 Day`

I tried to use [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

but it does not seem to work

Thanks

Comment: -1 *"but not works"* is not a programming question. And all PHP date/time questions have been asked and answered already. Use the search *more*. Voting to close now. (You can gain 500 reputation if you actually discover a PHP date-time question that has not been asked before. Just ping me if you think you've found one).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: i want to show diffrence b/w dates only in weeks,days @RajeevRanjan

Comment: week always having 7 days you can manipulate the figure of that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to **show difference only in weeks and days**, use this function:

```php
function diff_in_weeks_and_days($from, $to) {
    $day   = 24 * 3600;
    $from  = strtotime($from);
    $to    = strtotime($to) + $day;
    $diff  = abs($to - $from);
    $weeks = floor($diff / $day / 7);
    $days  = $diff / $day - $weeks * 7;
    $out   = array();
    if ($weeks) $out[] = "$weeks Week" . ($weeks > 1 ? 's' : '');
    if ($days)  $out[] = "$days Day" . ($days > 1 ? 's' : '');
    return implode(', ', $out);
}

echo diff_in_weeks_and_days('2013-12-18', '2013-12-26'); # 1 Week, 2 Days
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/82856)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

i think the best way is to use timestamp, then you can calculate the seconds between 2 dates and then convert it to days and weeks.

```
example:

$time1; // contains seconds since 1970
$time2;

$diff=$time2-$time1;

$days=($diff % 604800)/86400;
$weeks=($diff-($days*86400))/604800;

echo $weeks $days;
```

Comment: What about leapdays? Does UTC skip those?

Comment: no it does not skip that, because the time() function gets you seconds that have past since 1970.

Comment: Yup. But `86400` seconds in a day, not `3600` =)

Comment: ooh haha thnx 3600 1 hour

Answer (score 1):

Use the DateTime::diff() function

Example:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

Which will output:

```
+2 days
```

For more information, check [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) page

Comment: m having 5.2.3 version but this needs > 5.3.0

Comment: I'd recommend to upgrade to 5.3 tho